# Scala - MVN Package - how to add only one file change

Tags: java, scala, maven, jar

I inherited big scala project with many files/classes.

In order to do a change and test - need to:
1) Modify one file
2) MVN clean compile package
3) Test this new jar by running specific scala class that uses this built jar in step 2 (above)

For building a JAR - it takes 3-4min. How to speed up this process if only 1 file (and 1 line in it) is being changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize the build by using the following methods :-

1) Running maven build with Multiple threads works for me to speed up the builds. For example :

mvn clean install -T100
where -T is for specifying how many threads you want based on your hardware.

Below are the variants from wiki
Maven 3.x has the capability to perform parallel builds. The command is as follows:

mvn -T 4 clean install Builds with 4 threads

mvn -T 1C clean install 1 thread per cpu core

mvn -T 1.5C clean install 1.5 thread per cpu core

2) If you have written Junit Test and dont want to run test case every time you can use -DskipTests=true

3) Locally Install Nexus or Repositories
You can adjust memory configurations to optimum for eg: add this line to mvn.bat set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Also please refer http://bosy.dailydev.org/2009/02/speed-up-your-maven-build-four-times.html

Comment: This is MVN project (do not see SBT anywhere nor I think is allowed to change now to SBT) - is there a way to do with MVN? Thanks.

Comment: @user9750148 Please let me know if you have any further doubts.

Comment: Running without `parallel` was consistently faster than with -T flag.. (regardless of how many of them used) but thanks..